# Insert Into From SELECT query

Tags: sql, sql-server

This is my SQL code.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Basic]
(
  ID int,
  GroupCode int,
  program int
)

DECLARE @tblnum int

SELECT tblnum FROM dbo.Program

SET @Qry = 'SELECT Hits_ID, GroupCode  FROM dbo.' + @tblnum 

INSERT INTO [dbo].[Basic]
(
ID,
GroupCode 
)
EXEC sp_executesql @Qry
```

The problem is I need to insert values to the table `Basic` where `ID` and `GroupCode` will come from another table then column `program` should have the value of the variable `@tblnum`. And I don't know how to do that exactly. Kindly help. Thank you.

Comment: Why can't you just write a `INSERT ... SELECT`? Also, are you actually numbering your tables (`FROM dbo.' + @tblnum`)?

Comment: Can you post sample data with desired results?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you can include it as a constant:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Basic] (
  ID int,
  GroupCode int,
  program int
);

DECLARE @tblnum int;

SELECT tblnum FROM dbo.Program;

SET @Qry = 'SELECT Hits_ID, GroupCode, ''' + cast(@tblnum as varchar(255)) + ''' FROM dbo.' + @tblnum ;

INSERT INTO [dbo].[Basic](ID, GroupCode, program)
    EXEC sp_executesql @Qry;
```

You can also do it by passing the parameter to `sp_execute_sql`:

```
SET @Qry = 'SELECT Hits_ID, GroupCode, @tblnum FROM dbo.' + @tblnum ;

INSERT INTO [dbo].[Basic](ID, GroupCode, program)
    EXEC sp_executesql @Qry, N'@tblnum int', @tblnum = @tblnum;
```